# Is the new 'Cloud Firestore' able to query based location distance?

Tags: android, database, firebase, location, google-cloud-firestore

I know **Cloud Firestore** stores locations based on latitude and longitude in **Geopoints**. However, I can't find a method or a way documented to query documents based on the distance to a certain point, kind of what **GeoFire** does for the Realtime database.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something we're looking into, but isn't supported at this time.

Comment: See also this question specifically about GeoFire:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553682/is-there-a-way-to-use-geofire-with-firestore

Comment: Is it supported now?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the Geofirestore library.