# Filter location GeoPoint in distance radius - Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to search the Firestore database for the location Latitude and Longitude within a defined distance radius.

Sample Database:

```
COMPANIES
- COMPANY 1
--Lat: 12345 
--Long: 6789
- COMPANY 2
--Lat: 457851
--Long: 654214
- COMPANY 3
--Lat: 12345
--Long: 6789
- COMPANY 4
--Lat: 12463
--Long: 65487
```

**Note:** 
At Real Time I had the option to use GeoFire, but at Firestore I did not find any way.

How could you go through the database and find the Companies according to your Location, within a radius of distance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the new 'Cloud Firestore' able to query based location distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579698/is-the-new-cloud-firestore-able-to-query-based-location-distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't yet [support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579698/is-the-new-cloud-firestore-able-to-query-based-location-distance) though we're working on it. We also haven't [ported GeoFire to Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553682/is-there-a-way-to-use-geofire-with-firestore) given that effort is underway.

Comment: Any update on this? It has been 18 months and geo queries are somehow standard now

Comment: No updates, sorry. We're a small team with limited resources and have had to prioritize other things.