# Firebase + Geofire complex queries based on properties

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm producing a project with Firebase Realtime Database.

I have to post pictures with timestamp, latitude and longitude, and search for pictures in a radios from my position, ordered by timestamp and with the value of the timestamp 1 days from now.

Is Firebase Realtime Database + Geofire right for me?

I cannot figure out how to make queries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Realtime Database only supports one dimensional queries. So, if you did want to use 
the RTDB, you'd need a two-stage query.

1. geoquery all the pictures in your given center/radius.
2. for each of these pictures, query all the data for that picture.
3. Once the data arrives for all the pictures, filter/sort client side.

RTDB structure would be something like:

```
pictures/{pic_id}: {
  timestamp:,
  name:
  [,...]
},
geofire_pictures/{pic_id}: <geofire data>
```

With that said, I think RTDB would be a fine choice if you expect your 
result set sizes to be managable. If you need to scale, I would suggest [waiting for Firestore's geoquery functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553682/is-there-a-way-to-use-geofire-with-firestore).