# GeoJson and Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using mongoDB locally for an application that uses GeoJson and I am considering switching to firestore.
However, I do not seem to find information on its support for GeoSearches. Is it supported in firestore?

UPDATE: For python

Answer (score 0):

Support for geoqueries is currently not natively built into Firestore, but there's a documented workaround [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

There are also many third-party libraries for various platforms implementing the same approach, so I'd recommend searching for one for Python.

Also see:

- [Is there a way to use GeoFire with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553682/is-there-a-way-to-use-geofire-with-firestore/46554998#46554998)
- [How to run a geo "nearby" query with firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore/66354370#66354370)
- Video showing [how to do geoqueries on Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q)

Comment: Thanks. Should have stated for python in my question, sorry. Looks like I am stuck with MongoDB and with a local server (since Atlas is also an issue for GeoSearch)

Comment: Even thought the code samples are only for Android, iOS, and JavaScript, the solutions works the same across all platforms, so I recommend giving it a try in Python yourself. All you really need is a way to translate a lat/lon to a geohash, which I assume [exists in python too](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+geohash+example).

Comment: I know, I have already embedded a geohash of sort in my code as the original app was in erlang andIi needed to so geo search myself, so I might just revert back to that actually.